# Generate documentation from source code

Tags: programming

Is there a good program to generate documentation from C source code? For example, similar to javadoc, if I could write the documentation about the parameters and then create html documentation from the source code.

```
/* size_t: number of bytes of memory to allocate */
void *malloc(size_t nbytes) {
    if (nbytes == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

#if   STRATEGY == 1
    return malloc_first(nbytes);
#elif STRATEGY == 2
    return malloc_best(nbytes);
#elif STRATEGY == 3
    return malloc_worst(nbytes);
#elif STRATEGY == 4
    return malloc_quick(nbytes);
#else
    exit(1);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) is very much the standard for this *and has been for years* - you can annotate your functions and parameters to document them and it will extract:

- The annotated documentation
- The function & class signatures
- Called functions & calling functions,
- Lots more

It can be run from the command line but there is also a DoxyWizard to configure a project.

It can generate a large number of formats of documentation including htlm, htmlhelp, man, etc.

It can construct very nice documentation and can also add very good diagrams if you have [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) installed.

It can parse C, C++, Java, (Corba and Microsoft) Java, Python, VHDL, PHP IDL, C#, Fortran, TCL, Objective-C 2.0, and to some extent D sources.

It is Free, Gratis & Open Source.